# Error in named queries

Tags: hibernate

I am getting  `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: getPreferenceById` and this is my query

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getPreferenceById", 
    query = "select p from Preference p where p.profile.id=:Id") })
```

and this is my preference class

```
@Entity(name = "perference")
public class Preference {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Profile profile;

}
```

The query is for fetching the preference for the given profileId, (id), but it is giving error. I have a similar named query in the Profile class, but it is not giving error.

I found this in the stacktrace,

```
Error in named query: getPreferenceById
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Preference is not mapped 
[select p from Preference p where p.profile.id=:Id]
```

I have added the javax `@Entity` annotation to the preference class

What is wrong with this named query?

Comment: Please, add a full stack trace.

Comment: The class is probably not listed in your persistence.xml file, or in your hibernate configuration file. When asked to post the full stack trace, why don't you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I am not using xml configuration, it is java based/annotation driven configuration and the table preference is created in the database when i run the program without named query in preference class

Comment: can your able to post your repository  related code ?

Comment: Repository related code? you mean the function that use this named query?

Comment: are you using jpa?

Comment: I am not using spring jpa i am using hibernate as my persistence layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got that working by changing the `NamedQueries` to `NativeNamedQueries` i don't know why it worked

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a typo error, change `Preference`  to `preference`:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getPreferenceById", 
    query = "select p from preference p where p.profile.id=:Id") })
```

As you're using `@Entity(name = "perference")` to map your class.