# Managing both @NamedQueries and @NamedNativeQueries under the same Entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I wanted to use anotations in order to keep the code clean but all I get are headaches.

I know the problem has to do with a column's name with an underscore as: `rental_rate`. If I used @NamedQuery, it is going to throw an error.

Here are the anotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name="film")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Film.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.findById", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f WHERE f.filmId=:filmId")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.ratings", query = "SELECT f.rating FROM Film f")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.prices", query = "SELECT f.rental_rate FROM Film f")
})
```

The anotation that I am struggling with is:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Film.prices", query = "SELECT f.rental_rate FROM Film f")
```

it throws this error which I believe it has to do with the underscore in the column's name.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: Film.prices
```

After some research I found about @NamedNativeQuery in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627944/error-in-named-queries) and so I decided to change the anotation to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="film")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Film.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.findById", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f WHERE f.filmId=:filmId")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.ratings", query = "SELECT f.rating FROM Film f")
   //,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.prices", query = "SELECT f.rental_rate FROM Film f")
})

@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Film.prices", query = "SELECT f.rental_rate FROM Film f")
})
```

but then it would be outside the Entity

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.String
```

**How can I manage this issue?**

NOTES

- Java 8
- Netbeans 11
- JPA (Hibernate 4.3.1)

EDIT

Full class file

```
@Entity
@Table(name="film")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Film.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.findById", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f WHERE f.filmId=:filmId")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.ratings", query = "SELECT f.rating FROM Film f")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.prices", query = "SELECT f.rentalRate FROM Film f")
})

/*@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Film.prices", query = "SELECT f.rentalRate FROM Film f")
})*/
public class Film implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private int filmId;
    private String title;
    private String Description;
    private String releaseYear;
    @NaturalId
    private int languageId;
    @NaturalId
    @Column(nullable=true)
    private Integer originalLanguageId;
    private int rentalDuration;
    private float rentalRate;
    private int length;
    private float replacementCost;
    private String rating;
    private String specialFeatures;
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;    



    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "film_category",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "film_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") }
    )
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "inventory",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "film_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "inventory_id") }
    )
    private List<Store> stores = new ArrayList<Store>();


    public int getFilmId() {
        return filmId;
    }

    public void setFilmId(int filmId) {
        this.filmId = filmId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String Description) {
        this.Description = Description;
    }

    public String getReleaseYear() {
        return releaseYear;
    }

    public void setReleaseYear(String releaseYear) {
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    }

    public int getLanguageId() {
        return languageId;
    }

    public void setLanguageId(int languageId) {
        this.languageId = languageId;
    }

    public int getOriginalLanguageId() {
        return originalLanguageId;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguageId(int originalLanguageId) {
        this.originalLanguageId = originalLanguageId;
    }

    public int getRentalDuration() {
        return rentalDuration;
    }

    public void setRentalDuration(int rentalDuration) {
        this.rentalDuration = rentalDuration;
    }

    public float getRentalRate() {
        return rentalRate;
    }

    public void setRentalRate(float rentalRate) {
        this.rentalRate = rentalRate;
    }

    public int getLenght() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLenght(int lenght) {
        this.length = lenght;
    }

    public float getReplacementCost() {
        return replacementCost;
    }

    public void setReplacementCost(float replacementCost) {
        this.replacementCost = replacementCost;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getSpecialFeatures() {
        return specialFeatures;
    }

    public void setSpecialFeatures(String specialFeatures) {
        this.specialFeatures = specialFeatures;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Timestamp lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setCategories(Set<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public Set<Category> getCategories() {
        return this.categories;
    }

    public List<Store> getStores() {
        return stores;
    }

    public void setStores(List<Store> stores) {
        this.stores = stores;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Film{" + "filmId=" + filmId + ", title=" + title + ", Description=" + Description + ", releaseYear=" + releaseYear + ", languageId=" + languageId + ", originalLanguageId=" + originalLanguageId + ", rentalDuration=" + rentalDuration + ", rentalRate=" + rentalRate + ", length=" + length + ", replacementCost=" + replacementCost + ", rating=" + rating + ", specialFeatures=" + specialFeatures + ", lastUpdate=" + lastUpdate + ", categories=" + categories + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have attribute called `rental_rate` in Film?

Comment: @sc0der What do you mean by File?

Comment: I mean the Film entity, Does the attribute in the class called `rental_rate `?

Comment: Yeah it is, I tested the query on the DB and it works. I just don't get it why it doesn't in code. Maybe something hardcoded in hibernate?

Comment: I know that the DB col may be called `rental_rate` but in the class Did you declare it like `rentalRate`  or `rental_rate `

Comment: rentalRate, no way that is the problem... I'm going to test it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test if the attribute in `File` class is something like `rentalRate` not `rental_rate`

So in JPA, we use the attributes' names from the class not the columns' names in Database

1. Update your entity class and use `@Column` annotation with the name in the database and you can use any name related to java convention and use it in JPA
2. Check if your id is auto increment use `@GeneratedValue` annotation if not like PostgreSQL use this one where `name_seq` is the sequence name

```
    @SequenceGenerator(name="name_seq",
                       sequenceName="name_seq",
                       allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                    generator="name_seq")
```

, Entity

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int filmId;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String Description;
    @Column(name="release_year")
    private String releaseYear;
    @NaturalId
    private int languageId;
    @NaturalId
    @Column(name="original_languageId", nullable=true)
    private Integer originalLanguageId;
    @Column(name="rental_duration")
    private int rentalDuration;
    @Column(name="rental_rate")
    private float rentalRate;
    @Column(name="length")
    private int length;
    @Column(name="replacement_cost")
    private float replacementCost;
    @Column
    private String rating;
    @Column(name="special_features")
    private String specialFeatures;
    @Column(name="last_update")
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;
```

2. Update the query to match the attribute names in the Film class, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="film")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Film.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.findById", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f WHERE f.filmId=:filmId")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.ratings", query = "SELECT f.rating FROM Film f")
   ,@NamedQuery(name = "Film.prices", query = "SELECT f.rentalRate FROM Film f")
})
```

Comment: I know and test the other queries and work. This one throws me unknown Entity

Comment: Could you put `Film` class in your question

Comment: Ok, so the columns in the DB uses underscore between words like "rental_rate"?

Comment: yeah that one column and another which I also need. AND I can not change their names.